# Why properties inside @media print (div) not working?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, vb.net

I have set the crystal report in my website all the pages to be shown continuously, and when printing it i want to break the pages according to the division. I don't know what is wrong with my code, it isn't working in any browser. Here is the code inside the css, for @media print.

```
@media print {
  div#CrystalReportViewer1_ctl01 > div {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-after: always;
  }
}
```

Here is the is wht I've included as link in the .aspx:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" media="print"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

To know the division, I checked the inspect element (google chrome) and took the id of the division (CrystalReportViewer1_ctl01)

What I have tried:

I have tested the @media print by setting the background color of the body, and it worked(only when i pressed ctrl+p ). When printing the report, it doesnt maybe because of table. Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that the Id will always be `CrystalReportViewer1_ctl01`

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? I made [a codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BVmMBx), but it does seem to work as designed.

Comment: asp.net doesn't guarantee to generate the same ID for a server-generated element every time. I suggest you use a class or something instead, or maybe wrap the report element inside a static element whose ID you can guarantee.